# Factor analysis in R using factanal(), error

Tags: r

I am trying to do factor analysis on R using `factanal()`. I have given the code,

```
book1.fac<- factanal(book1.norm, factors= 10, rotation = "none", na.action = na.omit ).
```

But it shows an error. the message is,

```
Error in solve.default(cv) : 
system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 4.24096e-18.
```

can't understand what to do. Please help.

Comment: Seems to be a problem with your data. We need to see the data to give more information.

Comment: what does `dim(na.omit(book1.norm))` return?

Comment: @user20650, it returns with [1] 19  22.

Comment: @ekstroem, how can I made to see you the data? please let me know.

Comment: Try `dput(book1.norm)` if it is not too long

Comment: @Bappe; you are trying to extract 10 factors from 19 observations, and n < p, I am not surprised you are running into problems. Examine your data to see how many observations are being removed by na.omit, what the missing pattern is - ie is the missing dominated by one or two variables . Once happy, run fa.parallel from the psych package to get an idea of the number of factors to remove, and then try again.

Comment: @user20650, I have also tried with 3 factors, but it shows same error. Rest of the process, I will try and inform here.

Comment: @Bappa ; please note that for your data the n < p : ie number of rows is less than the number of columns so corr matrix cant be inverted. So just to see effect of fewer columns it with `factanal[book1.norm[,1:10], factors=3)`

Comment: ps lots of rules of thumb in fa - worth reading https://www.encorewiki.org/display/~nzhao/The+Minimum+Sample+Size+in+Factor+Analysis